# Who is this mysterious gentleman?

Tags: riddle

I help a lover win a heart,

I believe in chivalry,

I can be juvenile at times,

I hang out with the bar crowd.

Who or what am I?

HINT:

> The title of the riddle contains a hint in a form of an important historical reference.

HINT 2:

> I may have a body,
>  I wear a pony tail on my head.

HINT 3:

> People around think I am very judgemental

I am not a brand. 
You all have heard of me.
I may have even called you once or twice.

HINT 4:

> I tell people when they mess up royally

LAST HINT:

> Joffrey Baratheon

Comment: Updated the posed question. A "gentleman" in question doesn't have to be an animate object/person.

Comment: Is it some sort of name-branded alcohol with a mascot? Like Jack Daniel's or Captain Morgan's? Etc etc.

Comment: I will add to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems like noone is following my logic here :)

> I am Court

I help a lover win a heart,

> You pay court to somebody to win over their favor, aka courting

I believe in chivalry,

> Chivalry, often referred to courtly love, was a system of values developed and followed by the knights of the royal court

I can be juvenile at times,

> Juvenile courts try cases involving underage individuals

I hang out with the bar crowd.

> Bar crowd as in people of legal profession

Who or what am I?

> I am Court

HINT:

> The title of the riddle contains a hint in a form of an important historical reference. 
>  Historically gentlemen were nobility. Court titles often included the word gentleman.

HINT 2:

> I may have a body, 
>  Habeas corpus - a widely used courtroom term
>  I wear a pony tail on my head.
>  Lords and judges used to wear wigs made of horse hair

HINT 3:

> People around think I am very judgemental
>  Courts put people on trial and judge them

I am not a brand. You all have heard of me. I may have even called you once or twice.

> You might have been called to jury, or as witness

HINT 4:

> I tell people when they mess up royally
>  Courts tells us when we mess up. Royally is just an extra hint to help with above :)

LAST HINT:

> Joffrey Baratheon
>  He was/is a king, at court

Comment: In the future, you might want to give it more than 3 hours before you reveal the correct answer. Different members use the site at different times of day, and often puzzles go multiple days without an answer but are subsequently solved.

Comment: Right.  I shall do that next time.  I hope you liked it anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

It could be

> Cupid

I help a lover win a heart,

> Cupid's arrow makes people fall in love

I believe in chivalry,

> He is all about wooing women

I can be juvenile at times,

> He is portrayed as a baby

I hang out with the bar crowd.

> People use OKCupid to meet people and go out to bars with them

Who am I?

> You are Cupid

Comment: Fun answer, but no.

Comment: Chivalry is not about wooing women.  It's about the rules of mounted (horse) combat.

Comment: In this context it has to do with both, I think. Origins of the word chivalry are important here.

Comment: Yes technically chivalry is primarily about medieval combat, but in modern society it is almost exclusively about interacting with women. Very few people regularly use the word chivalry in today's world to talk about mounted combat. I feel that's fairly obvious